# GitSupport.sh permanently running, apparently hangs

Tags: macos, menu-bar, git

I have a niggling process that sometimes runs persistently, somewhat randomly, and sometimes cannot be cancelled. In the screenshot, there are three processes of the same running simultaneously. I'm wondering if anyone has seen this before. I'm not able to locate the process in the command line. I have Git installed for local web development, so it obviously relates to that, but I'm wondering what it's searching for, and why it hangs, and what I can do to make the process work and quit, instead of sometimes running perpetually.

[image: Screenshot of GitSupport.sh process]

Comment: git does not have GitSupport.sh as default - Seaech your disk and find where it is and read it. Also look in you LaunchAgens to see where it is launched

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case it was caused by the Right Click Booster app.

com.HobbyistSoftware.RightClick.RCPlugin/GitSupport.sh

Comment: Awesome! Can you elaborate on why (if you know?)

Answer (score -1):

Yessiree, I too had this happening on my beloved machine. Low and behold, Right Click Booster was the culprit. Actually, to be more specific, I started seeing this happen after I removed Right Click Booster from my system's startup list. I guess it got offended or something! After I uninstalled it the problem went away.

Comment: How does this differ or improve on the other answer?

Comment: How did you uninstall it at the end?